# SVCUTIL.EXE: Any way to separate my Commons.xsd classes? (C#)

Tags: c#, xsd, wsdl, svcutil.exe

Basically I have the following scenario:

I have 2 WSDL files:

- User.wsdl
- Customer.wsdl

Both of these wsdl's reference a Commons.xsd (Schema) so that they can use an Address ComplexType.

Then I do `svcutil.exe "User.wsdl" "Commons.xsd"` to generate the code for the User wsdl.
Then I do `svcutil.exe "Customer.wsdl" "Commons.xsd"` to generate the code for the Customer wsdl.

The problem is this: How do I get svcutil to put Address in it's own "Commons" namespace? As it stands right now, it creates an Address type in both of the output files (`User.cs` and `Customer.cs`) which cause a name collision, or if I specify a namespace now I have two Address types, each in their own namespace, which means I can't pass around the same reference between User and Customer for address (sometimes a user is also a customer, so they have identical addresses).

Is there some way of making svcutil split out the Address into its own namespace? And also, if it can put it in it's own file (`Common.cs`) that would rock too. But, I don't see a way for it to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

svcutil has a /namespace argument that allows you to map wsdl namespaces to a given code namespace.  You can provide this argument multiple times, but it's not well documented, so you may need to play around with it quite a bit... you can specify a wildcard, but I'm not sure if you can single out one namespace and wildcard the rest.

I'm not sure about this, but I think that if you do both wsdl's at the same time, I think they will combine into one .cs file... maybe it will be smart enough to not duplicate classes at that point.

For eg.

```
svcutil.exe "User.wsdl" "Customer.wsdl" "Commons.xsd"  
/n:UserAddressNamespace,User.Address  
/n:*,User
```

Hopefully that helpssome, I wish I could give you a better answer, but it's been a long time since I used wsdl's.